# What .TXT representation of linebreaks within cells will be correctly imported?

Tags: excel, windows-7, excel-2000

When I have a line break like this (created by my program, or as in this example by Excel itself):

[image]

the Excel import wizard misinterprets it like this:

[image]

How can I avoid this failure?

The advice in [Importing CSV with line breaks in Excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668678/importing-csv-with-line-breaks-in-excel-2007) did not help.

Workarounds by post-import editing are unacceptable.

EDIT: Dragging the .TXT into Excel gives a different failure:

[image]

EDIT: Untrue. Expanding the row reveals success:

[image]

EDIT: EDIT: Replacing Tab with comma does not give success from File|Open or drag.

ANSWER summary: The given representation works - provided the .TXT file import is done by dragging not File|Open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created your file locally (thanks for hex dump!) and when I Import or File->Open the file I get the same results. However, if I just drag the file into Excel I actually get the expected line breaks. I then created a similar file directly in Excel and saved it as a tab delimited file and repeated the same process with the same results. So the fact that Excel won't correctly import a file that it creates leads me to believe that this isn't possible.

The next thing that I tried was replacing your tab with a comma and this actually worked for the File->Open scenario but not for the Import.

My guess is that Excel assumes that if you are "importing" text then it assumes it isn't in a correct and known format already. So I would suggest just sticking to CSV best practices.

Comment: "if I just drag the file into Excel I actually get the expected line breaks". Here not. "replacing your tab with a comma and this actually worked for the File->Open scenario but not for the Import." Here neither worked. Thanks for the thought, but perhaps yours is a different version of Excel?

Comment: In both scenarios above, if I expand the row I see the full data. Excel doesn't vertically auto-expand during text import. Although I am running Excel 2010 I wouldn't imagine that that part of the engine would change too much.

Comment: Here, expanding the row works for the drag case. Thanks for the correction, and answer. Here, expanding the row does not work for the File|Open case, so I guess Excel 2010 is indeed different. However, if you post a screenshot of our success with File|Open of comma-seperated .TXT, it would be useful for the future. Thanks.