# Pulling data from Google Sheets into Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I currently have an Excel document that pulls data from another file hosted in SharePoint. I use ='WebFileAddress'!A1 to pull this information, and typically drag it across whenever I need to update.

The team that is updating the file in SharePoint is now transitioning their documentation into Google Sheets.

I'm wondering if there is a way to pull the data in a similar fashion that I did from SharePoint, from Google Sheets into Excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data from published Google spreadsheet to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481725/import-data-from-published-google-spreadsheet-to-excel)