# Newlines in csv import to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm importing a csv to Excel 2016 - using `GetData from Text/CSV` so I can predict datatypes, otherwise columns with hex codes come through as garbage

But it's creating new rows wherever there are entries that have newline characters, even though these are inside quotation marks e.g.

```
123 | "Hello.<newline>My name is Jam" | a3e3f3
```

is being parsed out as

```
123              | Hello.
My name is Jam   |
```

I found several suggestions from a very old thread using Excel 2007 -

[Importing CSV with line breaks in Excel 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668678/importing-csv-with-line-breaks-in-excel-2007)

but specifying UTF-8 doesn't work...

I've tried recording the VBA for it to look for variables I can change:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""MyWorkBook"";Extended Properties="""""), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT * FROM [MyWorkbook]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = _
    "MyWorkbook"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Doesn't look like there's anything in there I can change to say "IGNORE LINEBREAKS INSIDE COMMAS"

Comment: Is removing `<newline>` from the string before hand not an option?

Comment: Probably will have to be, I'm looking at that now because I can't see any way to specify this on the in-built importers