# How to add a line break in a cell to a csv in python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv, line-breaks

In the CSV editor in Vscode it looks like this:

[image: CSV editor]
this is one cell

my code where I add the line break:

```
lista=''
for i in value:
            lista = lista + i + '\n'
stock_bodega.append(lista)

 result = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(stock_bodega,inv_bodega)), columns =headers)
 result.to_csv(r''+funciones.RESULTS_PATH+FILE_NAME, header=True, index=False, sep=',', mode='w')
```

but if I open the csv with a text editor or excel it looks like this:

","0
0
0
","S
S
S

Excel:

[image]

expected output:

[image]

Comment: What is `value`?  What is `inv_bodega`?  Do you understand that `lista` is not a list?  You are just producing a long, multi-line string.

Comment: value is the values of dict, inv_bodega is a list with multiple strings, specifically lista,I understand that I am creating a multiline string, I thought it would work, until I saw in excel/csv that it is not so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw CSV would look something like:

```
Col_1,Col_2
"foo
Foo
FOO","1 I
2 II
3 III"
"bar
Bar
BAR","a A
b B
c C"
"baz
Baz
BAZ","4 $
5 %
6 ^"
```

When viewed as table, that will look something like:

```
+-------+-------+
| Col_1 | Col_2 |
+-------+-------+
| foo   | 1 I   |
| Foo   | 2 II  |
| FOO   | 3 III |
+-------+-------+
| bar   | a A   |
| Bar   | b B   |
| BAR   | c C   |
+-------+-------+
| baz   | 4 $   |
| Baz   | 5 %   |
| BAZ   | 6 ^   |
+-------+-------+
```

I can model this data in Python like:

```py
my_data = [
    [ "Col_1"         , "Col_2"            ],
    [ "foo\nFoo\nFOO" , "1 I\n2 II\n3 III" ],
    [ "bar\nBar\nBAR" , "a A\nb B\nc C"    ],
    [ "baz\nBaz\nBAZ" , "4 $\n5 %\n6 ^"    ],

]
```

I don't use Pandas, so I'll show writing that data structure to a CSV with the csv module:

```py
import csv

with open("output_rows.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(my_data)
```

Seeing your line:

```py
result = pandas.DataFrame(list(zip(stock_bodega,inv_bodega)), columns=headers)
```

I believe you could hand this structure off to Pandas with ease, maybe:

```py
result = pandas.DataFrame(my_data[1:], columns=my_data[0])
```

If I had a list of values that were supposed to end up joined together as a single multiline field in a column, like:

```py
col1_src = [
    ["foo", "Foo", "FOO"],
    ["bar", "Bar", "BAR"],
    ["baz", "Baz", "BAZ"],
]
```

Then, I'd iterate those lists and join them with a newline, like:

```py
col1_data = []
for line_values in col1_src:
    col1_data.append("\n".join(line_values))

print(col1_data)
```

```py
[
    "foo\nFoo\nFOO",
    "bar\nBar\nBAR",
    "baz\nBaz\nBAZ",
]
```

and

```py
col2_src = [
    ["1 I", "2 II", "3 III"],
    ["a A", "b B", "c C"],
    ["4 $", "5 %", "6 ^"],
]

col2_data = []
for line_values in col2_src:
    col2_data.append("\n".join(line_values))
```

```py
[
    "1 I\n2 II\n3 III",
    "a A\nb B\nc C",
    "4 $\n5 %\n6 ^",
]
```

Which I could pass to the csv.writer() (and probably Pandas):

```py
with open("output_cols.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Col_1", "Col_2"])
    writer.writerows(list(zip(col1_data, col2_data)))
```

**Update**

Regarding the data not looking correct in Excel.  I don't have Excel, but here's the data viewed in a few other spreadsheet apps:

| App | Image |
| --- | --- |
| macOS Numbers | [image: macOS Numbers] |
| Google Sheets | [image: Google Sheets] |
| Dropbox preview | [image: Dropbox preview] |

Anyways, you can try changing the `"\n"` to `"\r\n"` for the line endings, though the CSV spec states either is acceptable (so Excel should also accept either).

Also, there's this thread, [Importing CSV with line breaks in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2668678/246801).

Comment: I tried your solution, but when importing to excel I can't get the line break to appear, excel only lets me select the delimiter as a comma, I think I have to make another adjustment

Comment: @RodrigoParedes, added some screenshots of various spreadsheet apps (and previewer), and added a link about importing CSV w/linebreaks in Excel.

Comment: The solution I found was to use the function `to_excel()` from Pandas, and with the file created, in excel I use the option adjust text and it is readable, the idea is that everything will be generated automatically, but this is enough for me, thanks for your answer